# Visual Studio 2013 won't display Winforms, with error 'A reference to the component 'System' already exists in the project'

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013

We have recently upgrade to  VS2013 (SP2), with little issue, until now.

I have a Form that is displaying happily in Visual Studio 2010, however, when I switch to Design View, won't display the form, with the error (at line and column 0):

```
A reference to the component 'System' already exists.
```

No other Forms, out of many, are having this problem.

I've rebooted, reset user data, removed NodeJS Tools (it's not a NodeJS project, but just in case), can find no errors in the code, removing the 'using System;' reference obviously causes compile exceptions, and my Google-fu is failing me.

Can anyone let me know what is causing this error, and where I can go to investigate it further, or better still, fix it?

Comment: What happens if you create a new WinForms project (File > New > New Project). Does that work? If so, compare the text inside your `.csproj` file with the new project and look for bad or broken references.

Comment: @Dai I can create new forms in this project, and other projects, perfectly fine. I did create a new one, and copied the designer code over (deleting event handlers required in the business logic) and got the same error. As I didn't copy any business code, just designer created code, it's something about the code in the .Designer file, but there is nothing (I can see) obviously wrong in it. Comparing text in .proj files I will try, but the new project proj file will be highly sparse when compared wit the project with this form in it.

Comment: Look for `<Reference>` elements, that's where I think the problem lies.

Comment: @Dai, wow, thanks for the tip, you helped track that one down in under 10 minutes, after a day of frustration! Answer is below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Dai for the pointer that gave me the answer

I compared the <Reference> tags in the proj file with another proj file in the solution, and found that, in the project with the failing form, my System reference had somehow gained a HintPath:

```
<HintPath>..\..\..\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll</HintPath>
```

I removed it, and set it back to:

```
<Reference Include="System" />
```

After reloading the project, the form came back happily.

Comment: @GustavoMelo Glad this helped someone else!

Comment: I faced the same error also, version upgrade might cause this kind of problem, after upgraded VS2005 project to VS2017, my .csproj was missing the XML header and after I compare the VS2017 .csproj and the upgraded project .csproj and added the missing XML header into the .csproj, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by upgrading
my project framework from **2**.**0** to **latest** (in my case it was **4**.**6**.**1**)